# how to read a whole vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
  vector<int>test = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    cout<<test[0,8]<<'\n';
}
```

I want this code to print from 0 to 9 but it is only printing 9 and I also tried

```
cout<<test[0,test.size()]
```

but it is showing an "range error 9"....
Also please don't recommend me this code:

```
for(int x : test)
  cout<<x<<'\n';
```

because I don't  know how to use that x effectively....please help me this...

Comment: This is C++, not python dude! It is expected that it will print the element `test[8]` not the whole vector. The range based for loop is probably the simplest thing for you to do! `v.size()` is 9 which is clearly out of bound.

Comment: If you already know how to do it, then why are you asking how to do it, but also ask to not suggest the exact way how it is done?

Comment: Why the tag `atom-editor`?

Comment: Bro....I don't know how to use that x effectively....that's why....sorry I wrote it as I know how to use it effectively....

Comment: What do you mean "I don't know how to use that x effectively"?  Your example uses it just fine.

Comment: `for (const auto &x : test) std::cout << x << " ";` probably this is the most efficient and preferable way to use range-based for loop to print the whole vector. You don't need to optimise anything in that.

Comment: Can you please print the same in horizontal way....

Comment: @brc-dd: `" "` is probably less efficient than `' '`. The first is a null-terminated string containing a single space, the latter is just a single space. But I agree, this is unlikely to matter much.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `0,8` is using the [built-in *comma operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), and the result is the value on the right-hand side of the comma. In the case of `0,8` the result is `8`.

To print a whole vector you must use a loop, either directly as the one you seemingly don't want to use (why?) or indirectly through a function which contains a loop (like the `std::copy` call shown [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482003/440558)).

Comment: @SreeHari Because due to the comma-operator `test[0,8]` is `test[8]` which is the value `9` in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the content of the vector in to an outstream.

```
copy(begin(test), end(test), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

You need to include `iterator`

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example with comments for explanation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int>test = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // u need to add 0 to print it this is in case when u want print the vector content

  //scan the vector
  for(unsigned i=0; i<test.size(); i++)
      cout << test[i] << endl; // print out the vector item in the i position
}
```